# AngelScript - Avoid implicit default constructor from running

Tags: class, angelscript

I'm currently testing some simple AngelScript stuff, and noticed something I find a bit strange when it comes to how objects are initialized from classes.

Let's say I define a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    int i;

    MyClass(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

I can create an object of this class by doing this:

```
MyClass obj = MyClass(5);
```

However it seems I can also create an object by doing this:

```
MyClass obj;
```

The problem here is that `obj.i` becomes a default value as it is undefined. 
Additionally, adding a default constructor to my class and a print function call in each one reveals that when I do `MyClass obj = MyClass(5);` BOTH constructors are called, not just the one with the matching parameter. This seems risky to me, as it could initialize a lot of properties unnecessarily for this "ghost" instance.

I can avoid this double-initialization by using a handle, but this seems more like a work-around rather than a solution:

```
MyClass@ obj = MyClass(5);
```

So my question sums up to:

1. **Can I require a specific constructor to be called?**
2. **Can I prevent a default constructor from running?**
3. **What's the proper way to deal with required parameters when creating objects?**

---

Mind that this is purely in the AngelScript script language, completely separate from the C++ code of the host application. The host is from 2010 and is not open-source, and my knowledge of their implementation is very limited, so if the issue lies there, I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to declare class and send the value you choose to constructor try:
   MyClass obj(5);
2. To prevent using default constructor create it and use:

.

```
MyClass()
{
  abort("Trying to create uninitialized object of type that require init parameters");
}
```

or

```
{
  exit(1);
}
```

or

```
{
  assert(1>2,"Trying to create uninitialized object of type that require init parameters");
}
```

or

```
{
  engine.Exit();
}
```

in case that any of those is working in you environment.

declaring the constructor as private seems not to work in AS, unlike other languages.

Comment: I suppose the handle method is the way to go then. As for #2, perhaps the version of AngelScript being used here is too old, because I get an "Expected identifier" syntax error from setting a constructor as `private`. Thank you nonetheless; the handle _does_ work.

Comment: I fixed my answer. MyClass @ obj(5); didn't compile (I checked).

Comment: I fixed again my answer, after I checked that declaring of constructor as private realy don't work, as you said.

Comment: I tried the 4 solutions you added and none seemed to be recognized. They all gave syntax errors as if they were regular functions not matching a signature or `engine` not being declared. If that's supposed to work, it probably relies on something not implemented in my host application.